# Why variable referencing inside foreach in PHP works differently?

Tags: cakephp, foreach, pass-by-reference

Having some issues while variable referencing inside "foreach" loop.

This is my CakePHP code snippet:
http://pastebin.com/s7qtYahA

1st code assigns double assigning for the same number of inner "foreach" loop iteration.

But the 2nd code does everything OK.
Can anyone please clarify the twist..? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Please write a minimal test-case and post it as part of the question itself. Often times, in writing this minimal test-case, the reason/issue will be discovered ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $values has been reset/clear using array()

```
<?php
foreach($fields as &$field){
        $fieldValues = $this->controller->DomainFormFieldValue->find('all', array('conditions' => array('domain_form_field_id' => $field['DomainFormField']['id'])));
        foreach($fieldValues as $fieldValue){
                $field['DomainFormFieldValue'][] = $fieldValue['DomainFormFieldValue'];
        }
}
unset($field);
?>

2nd code:
<?php
foreach($fields as &$field){
        $fieldValues = $this->controller->DomainFormFieldValue->find('all', array('conditions' => array('domain_form_field_id' => $field['DomainFormField']['id'])));

        $values = array(); /* Array has been resetted */ 

        foreach($fieldValues as $fieldValue){
                $values[] = $fieldValue['DomainFormFieldValue'];
        }
        $field['DomainFormFieldValue'] = $values;
}
unset($field);
?>
```